# Could a library like Knockout be used to monitor DOM node insertion/removal?

Tags: model-view-controller, dom, mvvm, knockout.js

I have been looking for a while for a solution to monitor DOM node insertion/removal, without success. For example events like DOMnodeInserted are not cross-browser and are being deprecated.

I recently watched tutorials about libraries that implement MVC or MVVM patterns, like Backbone or Knockout. As such libraries monitor DOM elements, I was wondering if they could be used to monitor DOM node insertion/removal.

For example:

- if I have a select element on the page, I'd like to trigger an action when a new option gets added.
- if I have a table element on the page, I'd like to trigger an action when a row is added or removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't what Knockout does, and I don't think you'll find success there.

You *could* do something like binding your select elements to a KO observableArray, then monitor that array for changes. But that doesn't stop someone from manually inserting a select element into the DOM.

Bottom line: for KO, you're barking up the wrong tree.